# Run/Stop buttons hidden in XCode 4

Tags: xcode, button, view

I cannot get to the run and stop buttons outside of full screen mode in Xcode 4. Does anyone know how to get out of this view?

It is absurd that this is wasting my time. I should have never upgraded.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the XCode menu, select `View -> Show Toolbar`.

Comment: Neither of these worked for me but once I closed down the project and restarted it, they were back.

Answer (score 0):

That happens to me still in Xcode 5 and 6. I think the redraw just doesn't redraw the toolbar sometimes.

Try exiting out of full-screen mode ('View > Exit Full Screen' in Xcode 6), then going back to full-screen mode again. That usually triggers a refresh and the toolbar reappears.